# Mac python/pipenv environment got messed up by, I think, Saltstack install?

Tags: python, macos, pip, pipenv

I tried asking this on IRC, but haven't gotten any response.

So, somehow my pipenv on my mac in ~/.local/bin/pipenv got messed up, and it's trying to reference /opt/salt/bin/python3.7 ... I assume this is from some kind of saltstack installation, but I'm pretty sure I've never installed salt. this is a work laptop, so maybe my IT dept installed it, but I don't have and /opt/salt folder, and neither my system pip3, nor my virtualenv pip think pipenv is installed... any hints on how to figure out what installed it, or how to fix pipenv?

Comment: Have you spoken to your IT department?

Comment: If they did it, that's your answer. If not, they'll probably be able to help you set it up properly again. They may also be *very* interested if this isn't something that either you or they initiated.

Comment: What's weird is that saltstack isn't currently installed. I wonder if they used some other management system to temporarily install salt, then removed it? Idk, I'm just trying to figure out how to fix my python environment. [Insert link to the XKCD "Python Environment" comic]